# TestNG: How to skip @BeforeMethod call for some tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I am using TestNG for unit testing. I am using **@BeforeMethod** to save record and then execute the update, search, delete tests.

I am looking for the option where I can avoid executing **@BeforeMethod** method call for some test cases. For example, I have three tests save, update and delete. In this case, I only want to call **@BeforeMethod** for update and delete test not for save test. Any Idea?

Please note that, I don't want to use **@DependesOnMethods** as it is not recommended.

Thanks in advance.

**My Test class looks like below:**

```
@ContextConfiguration("file:application-context-test.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
public class MyEntityTest {

    int long myEntityId; 

    @BeforeMethod 
    public saveRecord(){
      session=getCurrentSessionFactory()
      myEntity = new myEntity();
      myEntityId = session.save(myEntity)
    }

    @Test
    public saveTest(){
      session=getCurrentSession()
      myEntity =session.getByID(myEntityId)
      session.save(myEntity)
    }

    @Test
    public updateTest(){
      session=getCurrentSession()
      myEntity =session.getByID(myEntityId)
      session.update(myEntity)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

TestNG supports native injection of some parameters, for example the information about the method to be called. So you could use the following approach:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
...
@BeforeMethod 
public saveRecord(Method method){
  if (!method.getName().equals("saveTest")) {
    session=getCurrentSessionFactory()
    myEntity = new myEntity();
    myEntityId = session.save(myEntity)
  }
}
```

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection

Answer (score 1):

you can groups in testing it will call a separate beforeMethod for different group
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups

Comment: As per discription on this page http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/BeforeMethod.html "For before methods (beforeSuite, beforeTest, beforeTestClass and beforeTestMethod, but not beforeGroups): If alwaysRun set to true, this configuration method will be run regardless of what groups it belongs to." This means @BeforeMethod belongs to a group will always be called even that group is not called for a test.

Comment: if you are using alwaysRun you are forcing it to execute. A simple code refactoring by calling the method annotated as @beforeMethod in your test method.

Comment: If @beforeMethod is used simple, how can I give the group name for this method. Also, alwaysRun is by default true. It will execute always even it does not belong to the group

Comment: you can call a particular method by removing the annotated @BeforeMethod in the test case you want to use or else you can listeners to by pass this beforeMethod invocation. AlwaysRun is by default false http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.testng/testng/6.8/org/testng/annotations/BeforeMethod.java?av=f

Comment: Could you please provide the link that may give the implementation for listeners to by pass this @beforeMethod invocation?